# Exporting a filename in bash profile with a specific extension

Tags: bash

I have a file in a folder that ends with *SUM.ext as follows

```
/Users/DA/xray/xmm/analyses/id_0141750501/0618_0141750501_SCX00000SUM.ext
```

and I have to export the path in bash_profile and source it in order to be able to do my analyses

```
export SOS="$anadir"/"$obsdir"/'0618_0141750501_SCX00000SUM.ext'
```

Here `$anadir` corresponds to  `Users/DA/xray/xmm/analyses` and `$obsdir` to `id_0141750501`. On each occasion, $obsdir changes, so do the file with "SUM.ext" extension and I need to source the new file for my analyses.

I tried the following but none of them find/store the correct full filename in the directory.

```
1) export SOS="$anadir"/"$obsdir"/"*SUM.ext"

2) export SOS="$anadir"/"$obsdir"/`ls -1 *SUM.ext`

3) sosname="${odfdir#/*SUM.ext}"
export SOS="$sasname"
```

Is there a way for me to be able to do this automatically without going through the hassle of modifying my bash_profile each time for each filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*" won't expand in variable creation process, try it like this:

```
SOS=$(ls "$anadir/$obsdir"/*SUM.ext)
[[ $SOS ]] && export SOS
```